# Should a function returning a boolean be used in an if statement?

Tags: swift

If I have a function call that returns true or false as the condition of an `if` statement, do I have to worry about Swift forking my code for efficiency?

For example,

```
if (resourceIsAvailable()) { //execute code }
```

If checking for the resource is computationally expensive, will Xcode wait or attempt to continue on with the code?

Is this worth using a completion handler?

What if the resource check must make a database call?

Comment: `do I have to worry about Swift forking my code for efficiency?` What?

Comment: If you make consecutive calls to Firebase, Xcode will sometimes run commands in parallel and complete prior to getting the response you intended back.

Comment: @Alexander if you’re going to leave a comment why not try to be useful

Comment: @CoddyHusk I'm asking for clarification. I have no idea what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

First off... **can** a function be used? Absolutely.

Second... should it be used?

A lot of that depends on the implementation of the function. If the function is known (to the person who wrote it) to take a long time to complete then I would expect that person to deal with that accordingly.

Thankfully with a lot of iOS things like that are taken out of the hands of the developer (mostly). CoreData and Network requests normally come with a completion handler. So any function that uses them would also need to be async and have a completion handler.

There is no fixed rule for this. My best advice would be...

1. If you can see the implementation of the function then try to work out what it’s doing.
2. If you can’t then give it a go. You could even use the time profiler in Xcode profiler to determine how long it is taking to complete.

The worst that could happen is you find it is slow and then change it for something else.